# Why root password?

Tags: ubuntu, password

The root password of Ubuntu is never be asked when I use apt-get, which instead asking my user password. i checked my user and root password to the same when installation, if later i change user password for some security reason, would the root password change too?

Comment: What is the precise command [you use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/457952/edit)?

Comment: On Ubuntu the user `root` does not have a password; that is, it is impossible to authenticate as `root` with a password. This is a good thing. Some user accounts, including by default the first user account created during system installation, are allowed to use the command `sudo` to run commands with root privileges; in order do this they must authenticate *as themselves*. So the root password won't change because there isn't any root password.

Comment: "the root password of Ubuntu is never be asked when I use apt-get," is not correct. It will be asked when appropriate: when software changes that is "root" owned it will

Answer (score 0):

Your user account and the root account are two different accounts. Changing the password for one, will not influence the other.

the `sudo` tool you are likely using allows you to execute commands as root after entering your user password, at least it is usually set up that way for administrative users.

the root password is needed if you want to log in as root or start a terminal session as root via `su`.

In a GUI terminal session, `passwd` will change your own password, while `sudo passwd`  or running `passwd` in a root session can change root's password.